# Arangodb: How to limit the user access at document level?

Tags: arangodb, aql

Base on [this documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-user-management/), access to databases as well as collections can be adjusted based on the user.

But is there anyway to limit a user (user's queries) so that he can only query against a specific document (and not the whole documents of a collection)?

Comment: Yes, if you use the Foxx microservices feature of Arango. It's not possible with the basic collection level security that is provided by Arango.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check that.